# Testing user input against dictionary file(JSON)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had a JSON file containing a large list of items in the following format:

```
[{"sku":43900,"name":"Duracell - AAA Batteries (4-Pack)","type":"HardGood","price":5.49,"upc":"041333424019","category": 
[{"id":"pcmcat312300050015","name":"Connected Home & Housewares"},{"id":"pcmcat248700050021","name":"Housewares"},{"id":"pcmcat303600050001","name":"Household Batteries"},{"id":"abcat0208002","name":"Alkaline Batteries"}],"shipping":5.49,"description":"Compatible with select electronic devices; AAA size; DURALOCK Power Preserve technology; 4-pack","manufacturer":"Duracell","model":"MN2400B4Z","url":"http://www.bestbuy.com/site/duracell-aaa-batteries-4-pack/43900.p?id=1051384074145&skuId=43900&cmp=RMXCC","image":"http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/4390/43900_sa.jpg"},
{"sku":48530,"name":"Duracell - AA 1.5V CopperTop Batteries (4-Pack)","type":"HardGood","price":5.49,"upc":"041333415017","category":[{"id":"pcmcat312300050015","name":"Connected Home & Housewares"},{"id":"pcmcat248700050021","name":"Housewares"},{"id":"pcmcat303600050001","name":"Household Batteries"},{"id":"abcat0208002","name":"Alkaline Batteries"}],"shipping":5.49,"description":"Long-lasting energy; DURALOCK Power Preserve technology; for toys, clocks, radios, games, remotes, PDAs and more","manufacturer":"Duracell","model":"MN1500B4Z","url":"http://www.bestbuy.com/site/duracell-aa-1-5v-coppertop-batteries-4-pack/48530.p?id=1099385268988&skuId=48530&cmp=RMXCC","image":"http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/4853/48530_sa.jpg"},
```

The task was to extract just the "name:" so and split it so that:
"name":"Duracell - AA 1.5V CopperTop Batteries (4-Pack)"

became

```
{key: "Duracell": AA 1.5V CopperTop Batteries (4-Pack)}
```

This is my code:

```
import json
data = {}
json_data = json.load(open(r'C:\Users\fionna.pereira\Desktop\products.json', encoding='utf-8'))
for item in range(len(json_data)):
   x = json_data[item]["name"]
   if x is None:
       continue
   else:
       y = x.split(' - ', 1)
       data = {k: v for k, v in zip(y[::2], y[1::2])} # Turn list entry into key/value pairs
       for key, value in data.items() :
        print(data)
```

The data output is as follows:

```
    {'Protec': 'Extended Life Wicking Filter for Select Humidifiers - White'}
{'Honeywell': 'True HEPA Replacement Filters for Select Honeywell Air Purifiers (2-Pack) - White'}
{'Dyson': 'Hard Floor Wipes for Dyson Hard DC56 Vacuums (1 Pack of 12 Wipes) - White'}
{'Aleratec': 'Drive Enclosure - Internal - Black'}
{'Amazon': 'Fire TV Stick'}
{'Proctor Silex': '4-Slice Toaster Oven - White'}
```

When I use the following code to retrieve keys, in order to test if the split really worked:

```
for key, value in data.items() :
        print(keys)
```

I receive the output(this is correct):

```
Protec
Honeywell
Dyson
Aleratec
Amazon
Proctor Silex
```

When I use the following to retrieve values:

```
for key, value in data.items() :
        print(values)
```

I receive the following output (this is also correct):

```
True HEPA Replacement Filters for Select Honeywell Air Purifiers (2-Pack) - White
Hard Floor Wipes for Dyson Hard DC56 Vacuums (1 Pack of 12 Wipes) - White
Drive Enclosure - Internal - Black
Fire TV Stick
4-Slice Toaster Oven - White
```

However, when I ask for user input to enter a key and return a value, nothing is coming up? This is the code I use for input:

```
import json
data = {}
json_data = json.load(open(r'C:\Users\fionna.pereira\Desktop\products.json', encoding='utf-8'))
for item in range(len(json_data)):
   x = json_data[item]["name"]
   if x is None:
       continue
   else:
       y = x.split(' - ', 1)
       data = {k: v for k, v in zip(y[::2], y[1::2])} # Turn list entry into key/value pairs
       key = input('Enter the key: ')
       if key in data:
           print('The value is:', data[key])
       elif key.title() in data:
        print('The value is:', data[key.title()])
```

Can somebody show me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this, hopefully it'll work better for you:

```
key = input('Enter the key: ')

for item in range(len(json_data)):
   x = json_data[item]["name"]
   if x is None:
       continue
   else:
       y = x.split(' - ', 1)
       data = {k.lower(): v for k, v in zip(y[::2], y[1::2])}
       if key.lower() in data:
           print('The value is:', data[key])
```

The first statement asks only once for the selection (you can wrap this in another loop to control that), rather than asking the user for every element in your data.

In the loop you're then rolling through the data to see whether the users entry matches it at all.

I am a little interested in why you never had any success with the data you provided, but if there are many more items in that file, the you would have been only matching against them one at a time, since you had to enter the search term for each item in the file whilst it's INSIDE the loop. ;-)

For a slightly easier version of this, which should be super easy to extend:

```
entered = input('Enter the key: ')

for item in json_data:
   if item["name"].find(" - ") > 0:
       name, item_desc = item["name"].split(' - ', 1)
       
       if entered.lower() == name.lower():
           print('The value is:', item_desc)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Omg. I tried the second suggestion you gave, and it worked! (It gives results! WOOHOO)Thank you SO SO much.  However, at the end of output, after it gives the input result.  It says this "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"  How do I bypass this error?

Comment: No worries at all. I've made a little edit to that second version, it's likely a result that can't split on " - " resulting in split() not returning the necessary values for `name, item_desc`: (expected 2, got 1) is the return value from split mismatching. Please mark the answer if you're happy, I'm new to answering and keen to obtain the kudos. Thanks and happy coding!!! ;-)